# Title bar not working properly on JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

I have a JInternalFrame class with a constructor that looks like this:

```
public MyInternalFrame() {
        super("Name");
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AutogeneFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AutogeneFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AutogeneFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AutogeneFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        initComponents();

    }
```

The problem is that the maximize, minimize, and exit buttons that should be in the top left corner of the window do not show up. However, the title "Name" does show up in the center of the title bar. I'm on a Mac, and rather than having the three little circles (red, yellow, and green) that are in the top left corner of all windows, they just appear as three little gray circles that are not clickable

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're constructing the [`JInternalFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#JInternalFrame%28java.lang.String%29) that "Creates a non-resizable, non-closable, non-maximizable, non-iconifiable `JInternalFrame` with the specified title." You want the one like this:

```
super("Name", true, true, true, true);
```

Comment: Needs one more `true` for `iconifiable`.

Answer (score 2):

Do not call `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()` in the constructor of the frame. Instead do it before creating the frame and from the EDT using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

Comment: Yes! See also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).